# Bolt CMS - Issue Linking Image Asset

Tags: bolt-cms

I am fairly new to Bolt CMS and CMSs in general. I am getting the hang of twig and things like that and have implemented a lot of dynamic content now. I am however having an issue on my timeline page in linking image assets.

I have a content type called news which has an imagelist field. I need to be able to pull the image path from the content type but when I get the raw path (ie. "files/2018-06/image-name.png") and do  nothing shows up. Is something wrong here? Is this an .htaccess issue?

I am open to any and all solutions. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Hi, im not 100% sure but if u mean like: `image src="[url]"` try and add a ' / ' in front of it. I had that once maybe its the same for u. Its probably no htacces issue but some problem with the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an imagefield in your record you usually can show the image with

```
{{ record.image|showimage() }}
```

or

```
<img src="{{ record.image|thumbnail(320, 240) }}">
```

For more information see: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.5/templating/twig-functionality#showimage and https://docs.bolt.cm/3.5/fields/image

You can also look how it is done in one of the example themes.